# get the sum of a column in dat file in unix in exponential form

Tags: unix, awk, exponential

I have a dat file for which sample is given below:

```
NYEFP 191800034103    20130225912131 JPYCNTG1 JPY 20130225POSTING from GMI                        QTY*MULT  -676500000.00SYS EFPSP                                      
NYEFP 291800034103    20130225912131 JPYCNTR1 JPY 20130225POSTING from GMI                        -(QTY*MU   676500000.00SYS EFPSP                                      
NYFX  191800034103    20130225912131 AUDCNTG2 AUD 20130225POSTING from GMI                        QTY*MULT -1200000000.00SYS FWDLL                                      
NYFX  291800034103    20130225912131 AUDCNTR2 AUD 20130225POSTING from GMI                        -(QTY*MU  1200000000.00SYS FWDLL
```

I want to get the sum of 10th field numeric part for all negative values together and for all positive values together. In this case SUM(1200000000+676500000) and negative sums.
Also I want this is exponential form.

Any ideas will be of great value

Comment: what is the exponential form you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a way:

```
awk '{if ($10+0>0) {a+=$10+0} else {b+=$10+0}} 
      END{printf "positive: %e \nnegative: %e\n", a, b}' file
```

Where `%e` stands for exponential format.

Note that `$10+0` expression is done to get rid of the text contained in the field. Hence, `676500000.00SYS` becomes `676500000.00`.

#### Test

```
$ awk '{if ($10+0>0) {a+=$10+0} else {b+=$10+0}} 
  END{printf "positive: %e \nnegative: %e\n", a, b}' a
positive: 1.876500e+09 
negative: -1.876500e+09
```

Comment: Sorry to come again.. I am new in this.. it worked when i ran it in the cmd line.. should I format it will work inside the perl script?

Comment: It should, @user2885163. Check also my updated answer, as I didn't add the exponential format in my first version.

Comment: The error I got is :String found where operator expected at ./GMI2GBS.pl_rinu line 273, near "awk '{if ($10+0>0) ..} else ....negative: " b}'"
        (Do you need to predeclare awk?)
Bareword found where operator expected at ./GMI2GBS.pl_rinu line 273, near "'{if ($10+0>0) {a+=$10+0} ... "negative: " b}' GMINY2GBS"
        (Missing operator before GMINY2GBS?)
syntax error at ./GMI2GBS.pl_rinu line 273, near "awk '{if ($10+0>0) {a+=$10+0} else {b+=$10+0}} END{print "positive: "a; print "negative: " b}'"
Execution of ./GMI2GBS.pl_rinu aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I am not familiar with Perl, I found this anyway: http://www.ehow.com/how_12194646_use-awk-perl.html Maybe it can help you. Otherwise update your question showing the whole code you are using now.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way:

```
awk '{gsub(/SYS/,"");$10>0?p+=$10:n+=$10}END{printf "pos:%E\nneg:%E\n",p,n}' file
pos:1.876500E+09
neg:-1.876500E+09
```